# Can't seem to lose this error: "You are trying to add a non-nullable field"

Tags: python, django

Regardless of what I do, I cannot seem to lose this error in a django model:

```
Did you rename twitterbot.bot to twitterbot.userbot (a ForeignKey)? [y/N] y
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'twitbot_id' to twitterbot without a default;
we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 2
```

As you can see here, I've set it up properly according to documentation, giving an "autofield".

So what is causing this error to persist? Creating Null = True / False seems to change nothing.

```
class TwitterBot(models.Model):
    twitbot_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    userbot = models.ForeignKey(UserBot)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True, null=True)
    screenname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    oauth_token = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True, null=True)
    oauth_token_secret = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True, null=True)
    hashtags = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Where is the field `twitterbot.bot`? Django complains about this.

Comment: I'm changing it. "userbot" is the previous 'bot'

Comment: "userbot is the previous bot", to the migration it means: remove `bot` field (no problem here), add new field `userbot` which is non-nullable. This can be probably solved with [RenameField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/migration-operations/#renamefield), so you'll need to edit your schemamigration before running migrate.

Comment: what is the message when you write `null=True`. If it's still bothering you and your app is in development you can try resetting db

Comment: Resetting the db did it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django adds a default "id" field to every model, you don't need an extra "twitbot_id" in your model. If a surrogate primary key is all you need, forget about "twitbot_id" because it will be a duplicate of the auto-generated "id". See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

If you add this and you already have TwitterBot objects in your database you must provide a default value to populate this column for existing rows in the database.